# Make a dot-plot in python

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to make a dot plot of two datasets. To simplify those two datasets, I'll put some letters

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([['a',1],['b',3],['c',4],['d',5],['e',6],['f',3]])
y = np.array([['c',3],['e',2],['b',6],['a',5],['h',5],['f',2]])

#in reality, those two arrays would be imported from two csv by np.genfromtext()...

xticks = x[0:5,0]
yticks = y[0:5,0]
x0 = np.array(range(1,6))
y0 = np.array(range(1,6))

plt.xticks(x0, xticks)
plt.yticks(y0, yticks)

#Here should be the dot plot...

plt.show()}
```

By dot-plot I refer to the fact that I'm comparing two gene samples, so the first column of the array corresponds to the gene name and the second to an associated value of the gen from that sample. In each array, the genes follow that order, they cannot be ordered.

So, what I'm trying to do is a plot where each coindicende ('b' with 'b' in both arrays, etc.) should be seen as a dot in that plot. Moreover, I would like to compare both numbers from each sample (for instance, (b1+b2)/abs(b1-b2) for each coincidence), so that those coincidences with numbers more alike are represented as darker spots (and those less alike lighter, or something like that).

Indeed, I managed to do so by iterating over each element in both arrays and making an array with the dot plot (here is the code in case you were interested, for the original code):

```
for fila in range(1, n):
    for columna in range(1, n):
        if tabla_final[fila,0] == tabla_final[0, columna]:
            y = np.log((float(tabla_A[fila,2])*float(tabla_B[fila,2]))/abs((float(tabla_A[fila,2])-float(tabla_B[fila,2]))))
            tabla_final[fila,columna] = y
        else:
            continue
```

The results I obtain (the dot plot) is like that (this dot-plot is exported to a csv):

This is a frame of the values for the comparison:
[image: This is a frame of the values for the comparison]

This would be the dot-plot (greener values are better associations and redder values are worse:
[image: This would be the dot-plot (greener values are better associations and redder values are worse]

This would be the case for same samples:
[image: This would be the case for same samples.]

Last but not least, as I will be comparing multiple samples two by two, I would like to obtain some sort of linear regression of this plot, with the Pearson's r coefficient as a way to assess the similarities of both samples.

Thank you for your advice

---

EDIT: I managed an algorithm to do that plot. My aim was to create one list with three columns, the forst being simply the range of elements on the x-axis, the second one the height of each point from the x-axis and the third one the values of the 'match' cell. (Actually, the current version of the algoritm does it from the top of the graph, so that the final result is inverted, as is more logical for these results to start everithing from (0,0)).

So, this is an algorithm that iterates over each column and each file, stopping at the first cell that is not empty (there is only one, so no problem with that), and adding the value of the cell to the third column from that list:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from scipy import stats as st
...
def crear_grafico(tabla, N, muestra_x, muestra_y):
tabla_valores = np.empty([N, 3], dtype = object)
tabla_valores[0: tabla_valores.shape[0],0] = range(1, tabla_valores.shape[0] + 1) #asigna a la 1ª col de 1 a N+1

for columna in range(1, N):
    contador = 1
    for fila in range(1, N):
        if tabla[fila, columna] == '':
            contador += 1
        elif tabla[fila, columna] != '':
            tabla_valores[columna-1, 1] = contador
            tabla_valores[columna-1, 2] = tabla[fila, columna]
            break
```

Afterwars, I returned three lists (x, y and colores) with the values of each non-empty column. Then, I use scipy to obtain the values for the linear regression and use matplotlib to do the graph:

```
 x, y, colores, contador = [], [], [], 0
 for elem in range(0,N):
        if tabla_valores[elem,2] == None:
            continue
        elif tabla_valores[elem,1] == None:
            continue
        else:
            x.append(tabla_valores[elem, 0])
            y.append(tabla_valores[elem, 1])
            colores.append(tabla_valores[elem,2])
            contador += 1


    plt.xlabel('%s' %(muestra_x[0:-5]))
    plt.ylabel('%s' % (muestra_y[0:-5]))
    plt.axis([-5, N+5, -5, N+5])
    cax = plt.scatter(x,y, c =(colores), alpha = 1, linewidths = 0.3, cmap = 'gnuplot')
    plt.colorbar(cax, label = '$\overline{x}_1$'+' x ' +'$\overline{x}_2$')

    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = st.linregress(x,y)

    y_regre = []
    for x in tabla_valores[0:N,0]:
        y_regre.append(intercept + slope * x)
    plt.plot(tabla_valores[0:N,0], y_regre, color = 'grey')
    if N == 100:
        plt.text(2, N-4, 'r = %.5s' %(abs(r_value)), size = 10, color = 'Blue')
        plt.text(2, N-12, 'n = %.5s' %(contador), size = 10, color = 'Blue')
    if N == 250:
        plt.text(10, N - 15, 'r = %.5s' % (abs(r_value)), size=10, color='Blue')
        plt.text(10, N - 30, 'n = %.5s' % (contador), size=10, color='Blue')
```

I put those lines for `N == 250` and `N == 100` so that the labels for the Pearson's r value and the number of samples were in-place.

Finally, I use call that function in main() and that's all:

```
def main():
    N =250
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(2,2,1)
    muestra_x, muestra_y = 'SATfinal', 'MBfinal'
    tabla = crear_tabla(N, muestra_x, muestra_y)
    crear_grafico(tabla, N, muestra_x, muestra_y)
    ...
    plt.show()
```

This would be the result:
[image: result]

Comment: You did succeed to create the dotplot. What, then, is your question? Are you only asking for a measure of similarity such as Pearson coefficient? I want to point out that your distance function (b1+b2)/abs(b1-b2) possibly results in error in case of b1=b2 which results in division by zero. Therefore I suggest other distance measurements such as Euclidean Distance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

Comment: Well, in that moment I did not succeed to do the dot plot as what I was using was Excel, and I wanted something more dinamic with python. However, some weeks ago I manage to do it, so thank you anyway.

Comment: If you find the time to do so, it would be great if you could provide your solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a nested for loop here, to iterate over the two datasets, and calculate the '(b1+b2)/abs(b1-b2)' parameter if the condition (b in first dataset and b in second dataset) holds. You can then fill a 2d list with the respective values and use matplotlib.pyplot.imshow() to generate a heatmap.

Some pseudocode to show what I mean:

```
heatmap = [[]]  # 2d list for the heatmap
for a in dataset1:
  row = []  # Contains comparison results of a to whole dataset2
  for b in dataset2:
    # These nested for loops iterates over the whole datasets and 
    # compare all values to one another
    if a in dataset2:
      # If this holds, we know a is in both datasets
      calculate parameter
    else:
      parameter = 0
    row.append(parameter)
  heatmap.append(row)

plt.imshow(heatmap)
```